# Cordova/Phonegap Plugin - Android - Session was closed properly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am using `https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin` for facebook login in my cordova based android app. I was testing the app with Facebook login feature, after a certain no of log in, i started getting an error saying

```
{"errorMessage":"Facebook error: Session was closed and was not closed normally"}.
```

The app is actually connecting to facebook app, But i get an error response. Totally lost. Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. May help someone so sharing it. I did not create an Android platform for Facebook App.
Add android Platform in Facebook App. Do not forget to mention the Key hash, this wont work without key hash.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you call to logout otherwise the session will expire..

facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function (response) {

```
  alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  }, function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
```

otherwise use long-lived facebook token since this is due to session expiring

Comment: Did you try to Add the Key hash??

Comment: Yes I did it seems it the fb error SessionState CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED from facebookConnectPlugin.    The error also happen when the hash key is not of fb as well

Comment: As per the updated answer when i tried to logout i got a message saying there is no session to logout. My Problem was due to the key hash and the session error was solved after providing the key hash

Comment: @SnehaS am not sure but may be the question has to answers depending on the situation this worked for me